# How to enable qDebug::noquote inside qMessageHandler?

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

How to enable

> qDebug::noquote

inside custom message handler in Qt?

Without using qDebug().noquote()

> qDebug().noquote() <<

every time.

Comment: If you have a custom message handler, what do you mean by *using qDebug().noquote() every time*? Do you many calls to `qDebug().noquote()`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call '*noquote*()' every time, as it is said in [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#noquote):

> **QDebug &QDebug::noquote()**
>
> Disables automatic insertion of quotation
>   characters around QChar, QString and QByteArray contents and returns a
>   reference to the stream.
>
> When quoting is disabled, these types are printed without quotation
>   characters and without escaping of non-printable characters.

If you use it inside a custom message handler, it would suffice to call '*noquote*()' in the constructor.